# Remove line break characters in multi-line XML element

Tags: perl, awk, sed

On a Unix system I have an input text file containing long multi-line strings.

I now want to remove line breaks only between two patterns ( and ) which can be on different lines.

Example input file:

```
text1 text2 <remarks> text3
text4 text5 </remarks> text6 text7 text8
```

Result output for the above input file should be:

```
text1 text2 <remarks> text3 text4 text5 </remarks> text6 text7 text8
```

I would prefer to use sed or Perl or maybe awk to do the job.

I do not see a solution as the newlines can happen "randomly" and text is just some log messages.

Here is a more detailed look of the input file I need to process. It does not contain a root XML section, but for testing I might just add one manually. Also there may be many "remarks" sections.

Inputfile Snippet (as it is very long), Filename is test:

```
<paymentTerm keyValue1="8" objectType="PAYMENTTERM" />
<paymentType keyValue1="20" objectType="PAYMENTTYPE" />
<priceList keyValue1="1" objectType="PRICELIST" />
<remarks>Zollanmeldung ab 250 €
Lager Adresse:
Hessen-Ring 456
D-64546 Mörfelden-Walldorff
eine Stunde vor Ankunft melden unter Mobile

Neu Spedition
A&amp;R Logistics Group
Storkenburgstrasse 99
D-62546 Mörfelden-Walldorf
www.asp.de</remarks>
<salesPersons>
<PERSON keyValue1="2" keyValue2="SALESEMPLOYEE" objectType="PERSON" />
</salesPersons>
<shippingType keyValue1="5" objectType="SHIPPINGTYPE" />
```

As stated above I want to remove the linebreaks ONLY between the patterns "remarks" and "/remarks".

I tried the Perl XML Parsing suggested by borodin like this:

```
use strict;
   use warnings 'all';

   use XML::Twig;

   use constant XML_FILE => 'test';

   my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
       twig_handlers => {
           remarks => sub { $_->set_text($_->trimmed_text) }
       }
   );

   $twig->parsefile(XML_FILE);

   $twig->print;
```

It works, but prints everything on one line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like an XML parsing problem. Is it?

Comment: Yes. It is an audit log I need to parse which has an XML syntax.

Comment: If your data is XML then you should say so. It is far better to use an appropriate module to process this sort of data than to try to hack something with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='</?remarks>' -v ORS= '!(NR%2){gsub(/\n/,OFS)} {print $0 RT}' file
text1 text2 <remarks> text3 text4 text5 </remarks> text6 text7 text8
```

Comment: This seems to work! But how can I just reformat the lines between those patterns and leave the rest of the file untouched so I have everything in one file at the end?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but maybe "add `-i inplace`" is the answer (see the gawk man page)? Or `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`? I'm assuming you're asking how to change lines mid-file ad the answer is - you can't do that with any UNIX too, you have to generate a new file and copy it back to the original one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

XML can represent the same information in many different ways, and it is always a risk to try processing it using regular expressions. It is far better to use a proper XML module to process XML data. This solution uses
[`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig)

In the constructor for the `$twig` object you can specify a callback which is called automatically every time a given XML element is encountered in the input

The `trimmed_text` method removes leading and trailing whitespace from the text of the element, and turns any internal whitespace sequences, including line breaks, into a single space. That is exactly what you are asking for here, so a call to `set_text` is all that is necessary to update the string

The file to be processed is specified by the `XML_FILE` constant and you should modify that to specify the path to your own data file. The modified XML is printed to `STDOUT`

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-8) /;

use XML::Twig;

use constant XML_FILE => 'remarks.xml';

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    keep_spaces => 1,
    twig_handlers => {
        remarks => sub { $_->set_text($_->trimmed_text) }
    }
);

$twig->parsefile(XML_FILE);

$twig->print;
```

#### input

Your sample data is invalid XML, so I have edited it to look like this. I have added the XML declaration that you said in a comment that you had, and I have added a root element `<data>`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<paymentTerm keyValue1="8" objectType="PAYMENTTERM" />
<paymentType keyValue1="20" objectType="PAYMENTTYPE" />
<priceList keyValue1="1" objectType="PRICELIST" />
<remarks>Zollanmeldung ab 250 €
Lager Adresse:
Hessen-Ring 456
D-64546 Mörfelden-Walldorff
eine Stunde vor Ankunft melden unter Mobile

Neu Spedition
A&amp;R Logistics Group
Storkenburgstrasse 99
D-62546 Mörfelden-Walldorf
www.asp.de</remarks>
<salesPersons>
<PERSON keyValue1="2" keyValue2="SALESEMPLOYEE" objectType="PERSON" />
</salesPersons>
<shippingType keyValue1="5" objectType="SHIPPINGTYPE" />
</data>
```

#### output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<paymentTerm keyValue1="8" objectType="PAYMENTTERM"/>
<paymentType keyValue1="20" objectType="PAYMENTTYPE"/>
<priceList keyValue1="1" objectType="PRICELIST"/>
<remarks>Zollanmeldung ab 250 € Lager Adresse: Hessen-Ring 456 D-64546 Mörfelden-Walldorff eine Stunde vor Ankunft melden unter Mobile Neu Spedition A&amp;R Logistics Group Storkenburgstrasse 99 D-62546 Mörfelden-Walldorf www.asp.de</remarks>
<salesPersons>
<PERSON keyValue1="2" keyValue2="SALESEMPLOYEE" objectType="PERSON"/>
</salesPersons>
<shippingType keyValue1="5" objectType="SHIPPINGTYPE"/>
</data>
```

Comment: Probably I was not precise enough. Sorry for this. The inputfile contains many other XML sections. I only need to modify the one with <remarks> and </remarks>. The rest should stay without modifications. How can this be done with your script?

Comment: @Bernhard: That is what it does. Why don't you try it? If you look at the `twig_handlers` you will see that there is a single entry for `remarks` elements which does `$_->set_text($_->trimmed_text)` which is all that is necessary.

Comment: I tried it. It works fine when there is only a remarks section. But when I added other sections I got this message:

`$ perl reformat

junk after document element at line 4, column 0, byte 110 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22/x86_64-cygwin-threads/XML/Parser.pm line 187.
 at reformat line 14.
 at reformat line 14.`

Comment: The inputfile is like this : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<remarks> test4 test5test6 test7 test8
test444 test75475 test089898 test787384
test9 test10 test11 </remarks>
<newtag>hello</newtag>
`

Comment: @Bernhard: Are you sure? That's not valid XML data. There must be only a single root element. What happened when you tried my code?

Comment: I had an error in the inputfile. Inputfile looks correct now:  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<audit-log>
<remarks> test4 test5test6 test7 test8
test444 test75475 test089898 test787384
test9 test10 test11 </remarks>
<newtag>hello</newtag>
</audit-log>
`. The script run now works but produces just everything in one line: `$ perl reformat
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<audit-log><remarks>test4 test5test6 test7 test8 test444 test75475 test089898 test787384 test9 test10 test11</remarks><newtag>hello</newtag></audit-log>`

Comment: Please copy and paste the XML *exactly as it is* into the question. I also need to see what is in `reformat`. What I wrote expects a file as a parameter as I said.  I'm done for the day and will take a look tomorrow.

Comment: @Bernhard: Please take a look at my revised answer. I have added the `keep_spaces` option to the constructor which prevents the module from discarding insignificant spaces when the data is processed. I have also set the default file handle mode to `:encoding(UTF-8)`. Note that I had to alter your sample data as I have shown. Please always post valid data that exhibits the issue that you are describing; if we have to edit what you have posted just to make it valid then there's always a chance that we have altered your data to make it unrepresentative of your situation.